# Calculation of survey weights when some respondents are certain to be selected

Tags: survey-sampling, survey-weights

I am helping with the design of a household survey which will use a four-stage sampling process, and I am unsure how to account for some elements of the population being selected with 100% probability. In particular, how this will affect the design weights and if this will affect the calculation of any population estimates in any other way.

The proposed sampling design is as follows:

Stage 1 - Municipalities will be selected within the State being studied. We plan to automatically select the largest municipality and then select five other municipalities without replacement using PPS based on the population of the municipalities.

Stage 2 - Villages will be selected within the municipalities using simple random sampling.

Stage 3 – Households will be selected in each village by simple random sampling from a list of all households.

Stage 4 - Respondents will be selected in each household. In all households, the head of the household will be automatically selected. If there is more than one other household member, one more respondent will be selected by simple random sampling from the remaining household members.

To calculate the design weight to use in analysis for population estimates (proportions etc.), I understand I need to calculate the probability of selection for each element at each stage of the selection process, multiply these together and then the design weight is the reciprocal of this.

**Question 1:**
Am I correct that for respondents who are household heads the probability of selection is simply taken as 1 at stage 4. Similarly for the largest municipality, the probability of selection is also taken as 1 at stage 1?

**Question 2:**
Will selecting the largest municipality and household head with certainty affect any other aspect of the analysis of population estimates (proportions etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Good question Leon,

You are correct that your probability is 1 for both the largest municipality and for the head of household.

As for your second question, *mathematicaly* this will not affect your outcome, but you do need to think about the bias that you are adding into your study. For example, let's pretend that this is a political survey your running prior to an election. In this case, by guaranteeing the inclusion of the largest municipality in your study, you're probably biasing towards a more metropolitan voting base-- in the U.S. this would cause you to most likely over sample Democrats over Republicans. Head of household would probably tend to bias in the other direction, as head of households tend to be older and somewhat skewed towards male, a largely Republican constituent.

So if you told me this was the study design you were following for this political study, I would be worried about the representativeness of your study. I'm sure you have good reasons for performing the sampling in the way you are, but make sure to consider if you are biasing your study.

Comment: One usually employs a quantitative method to analyze such survey data, rather than relying on the hope that biases cancel out.  One example is the [Hurwitz-Thompson estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horvitz%E2%80%93Thompson_estimator).  Mathematically, this *does* affect the estimates.